# How can I get doom-modeline to show the correct number of new emails?

Tags: mode-line, mu4e, doom

Doom-modeline has a feature where it shows the number of new emails you have. But for some reason, they're capped at 99, so the modeline always shows `99+`, no matter what. How can I get this to show the actual number of emails?

I'm using a vanilla Doom config, with the `mu4e` module enabled, and the modeline enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `doom-modeline-number-limit` to an infinite number.